# Selenium Web-Driver Popup

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[I am unable to write on this popup message using selenium.
Please feel free to help me in this case.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARQU2.png)
My Code is:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:\\gecko_driver\\geckodriver-
v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.heycare.com");
```

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/header/div/nav/div/a")).click();

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println("hello world-----1");
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.findElement(By.id("mobile")).sendKeys("7015273543");
System.out.println("hello world-----2");
//Driver.findElement(By.id("mobile")).sendKeys("7015273543");
driver.findElement(By.id("Pass")).sendKeys("123456");
}
```

Error:- 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: *[name='mobile']

Code is working fine till:-
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/header/div/nav/div/a")).click();
Unable to write on that popup form that comes after clicking on the login button..

Answer (score 0):

I navigated to that website and successfully targetted the mobile number field using this css selector `#mobile` which targets the id attribute.  You're doing this for your password field.  Try having your test use this:

```
Driver.findElement(By.id("mobile")).sendKeys("7015273543");
```

See if that helps...

**Edit**:  I'm not sure that the unformatted code block you're showing that switches frames is necessary.  Unless you're working with iframes, I didn't see any in the minute I was looking around.

**Edit2**:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.heycare.com");
System.out.println("hello world");

driver.findElement(By.className("log-pop")).click(); 

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("mobile")));

driver.findElement(By.name("mobile")).sendKeys("7015273543");
driver.findElement(By.id("Pass")).sendKeys("123456");
```

You could try something like this, I added in a call to WebDriverWait to account for the possible delay between clicking the login button, and waiting for the login prompt popup to finish it's animation prior to be allowed to be clicked.  I'm not sure if this will work in your case, but it's a possibility I sniffed out when I was observing the site's behavior.
(I didn't test any of this code, it's freehand written.  So take it with a grain of salt.  It might not work flawlessly as is.

Bit of java nit, you should make your object references lowercase, save capitalized symbols for class names.  I had a moment of trying to figure out why you were calling static methods of a class called `Driver` instead of an instance of the class `WebDriver`

Comment: Still got the same error after.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #mobile

Comment: Is this in a test method?  Are you sharing your full code?  Could you update your question to properly format the entire code you're using in a coherently formatted way?  I can't really tell what you're doing.  It sounds like the real problem may be that you're not getting that popup to open in the first place?  Can you confirm whether your xpath query is successfully opening the dialog prompt?

Comment: My code is working fine till the the click event.
As soon as the POPUP form comes i am unable to write anything on it.


CODE:- 
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:\\gecko_driver\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
   WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.get("https://www.heycare.com");
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/header/div/nav/div/a")).click(); //POP Opens
   driver.switchTo().frame(0);
   driver.findElement(By.id("mobile")).sendKeys("7015273543");
   driver.findElement(By.id("Pass")).sendKeys("123");

Comment: I meant to update your original question so you can do code formatting.  See my latest addition, it sounds like you're successfully getting the popup to appear, so I would say to try using WebDriverWait like my example shows to see if that helps at all.  The animation could be creating a delay where the fields can't be interacted with while it slides into view